# Having issue while changing values in pie chart flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I tried this code and its working fine for the first time.

```
double a = 2, b = 3, c = 5;
var color;
Map<String, double> dataMap = Map();
List<Color> colorList = [
  Colors.red,
  Colors.green,
  Colors.yellow,
];

void changeGraph() {
  dataMap.putIfAbsent("Fat", () => c);
  dataMap.putIfAbsent("Protein", () => b);
  dataMap.putIfAbsent("Carbs", () => a);
}

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  changeGraph();
}
```

and

```
PieChart(
  dataMap: dataMap,
  animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
  chartLegendSpacing: 32.0,
  chartRadius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.7,
  showChartValuesInPercentage: true,
  showChartValues: true,
  showChartValuesOutside: false,
  chartValueBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
  colorList: colorList,
  showLegends: true,
  legendPosition: LegendPosition.right,
  decimalPlaces: 1,
  showChartValueLabel: true,
  initialAngle: 0,
  chartValueStyle: defaultChartValueStyle.copyWith(
    color: Colors.blueGrey[900].withOpacity(0.9),
  ),
  chartType: ChartType.disc,
)
```

then after getting values from user i tried this method for changing the graph

```
setState(() {
  a = newA;
  b = newB;
  c = newC;
});
```

also i try to call **changeGraph()** method but the graph is not changing and its showing the value that it shows first time.
Is there any way to change the values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your'e doing here is changing the values of the variables only and not the values inside the map.The map has the value of a = 2 and not a reference to a.

Meaning that when you say `dataMap.putIfAbsent("Carbs", () => a);` the value of "Carbs" is not a but it's actually 2 since the value here is an int and not a reference.

In order to change the value of Carbs in the map you need to directly change it from the map itself by doing for example `datamap["Carbs"] = newA`. Same goes to b and c

Let me know if that doesn't work